# how to print a uint16 monochrome image in Qt?

Tags: qt, monochrome, uint16

I'm trying to print a image from a Dicom file. I pass the raw data to a convertToFormat_RGB888 function. As far as I know, Qt can't handle monochrome 16 bits images.

Here's the original image (converted to jpg here):
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/16bitc.jpg/

```
bool convertToFormat_RGB888(gdcm::Image const & gimage, char *buffer, QImage* &imageQt)
```

Inside this function, I get inside this...

```
...
else if (gimage.GetPixelFormat() == gdcm::PixelFormat::UINT16)
    {
        short *buffer16 = (short*)buffer;
        unsigned char *ubuffer = new unsigned char[dimX*dimY*3];
        unsigned char *pubuffer = ubuffer;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimX*dimY; i++)
        {
             *pubuffer++ = *buffer16;
             *pubuffer++ = *buffer16;
             *pubuffer++ = *buffer16;
              buffer16++;
        }
        imageQt = new QImage(ubuffer, dimX, dimY, QImage::Format_RGB888);
...
```

This code is a little adaptation from here:
gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.0/html/ConvertToQImage_8cxx-example.html

But the original one I got a execution error. Using mine at least I get an image, but it's not the same.

Here is the new image (converted to jpg here):
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/204/8bitz.jpg/

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get values of pixels from buffer manually and pass it to QImage::setPixel. It can be simplier.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning 16-bit integer to 8-bit variables here:

```
*pubuffer++ = *buffer16;
```

The result is undefined and most compilers just move the lower 8 bits to the destination. You want the upper 8 bits

```
*pubuffer++ = (*buffer16) >> 8;
```

The other issue is endianness. Depending to the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the source data, you may need to call one of the [QtEndian](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtendian.html) functions.

Lastly, you don't really need to use any of the 32 or 24-bit Qt image formats. Use 8-bit `QImage::Format_Indexed8` and set the [color table](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setColorTable) to grays.

Comment: Using the first suggestion, I get this image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/802/answer.jpg/  It's a lot darker, but it's closer to the desired one. Now I'm trying to change the color table, but I'm lost. I'll read in Qt's documentation and Google and see if I can improve this.

Comment: I've tried to change the color table, with     QVector<QRgb> table( 256 );
                    for( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
                    {
                        table[i] = qRgb(i,i,i);
                    }
                    imageQt->setColorTable(table);  
I get the same image. I'm stuck.

Comment: How about change the type of buffer16 to unsigned short? The type casting from unsigned to signed probably screwed up.

Comment: Hmmm, I get the same dark image. Another thing: the original image returns true with 'if (gimage.GetPhotometricInterpretation() == gdcm::PhotometricInterpretation::MONOCHROME2)'. I don't know if I should multiply by 3 in ubuffer...

Comment: Looks like some gdcm issue. I am not familiar with gdcm at all. Sorry.